How can I use workflow_call input as env?
My SHA/commit-hash doesn't get printed in the called workflow. I have 2 workflow as a simple python file:
call_other_workflow.yml:
name: call other workflow

on:
  push

jobs:

  #------------------------------------
  prep:
    name: prep
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      sha:
        ${{ steps.short-sha.outputs.sha }}
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4.1.1
        with:
          submodules: recursive
      - name: Short-Sha
        uses: benjlevesque/short-sha@v3.0
        id: short-sha
        with:
          length: 8
  #------------------------------------
  call-other-workflow:
    name: call-other-workflow
    needs: [ prep ]
    uses: ./.github/workflows/other_workflow.yml
    with:
      commit-hash: ${{ needs.prep.outputs.sha }}

other_workflow.yml:
name: other workflow

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      commit-hash:
        description: Hash of the commit
        type: string
        required: true

  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      commit-hash:
        description: Hash of the commit
        type: string
        required: true

jobs:

  #------------------------------------
  prep:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Print SHA
        run: echo "${{ inputs.commit-hash }}"

      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4.1.1
        with:
          submodules: recursive

      - name: Call python script
        env:
          COMMIT_HASH: ${{ github.event.inputs.commit-hash }}
        run: python3 scripts/print_commit_hash.py

..and a simple python-file:
scripts/print_commit_hash.py:
import os

print(os.environ["COMMIT_HASH"])

When this has run, I can see that the SHA makes it to the 'other_workflow.yml', looking at [Set up job > Inputs], but in [Call python script > env: COMMIT_HASH: ] it shows as empty. When I call other_workflow.yml manually the 'input' gets printed. What is going (wr)on(g)?

Why not use the inputs context?

Ehm. Sorry, I'm under the (potentially false) impression that I am using the 'inputs context'. Can you please elaborate?

github.event.inputs.commit-hash is using the GitHub context.

Thank you very much. using inputs.commit-hash instead worked indeed. Why does that make a difference? Why is there even the 2 options? I really find the github-actions syntax quiet frustrating. :-/ Many thanks again @jonrsharpe.
